# How to get second elsif statement to work

Tags: ruby

I am converting from C to F and vice-versa. My code is:

```
puts "Please input temperature"
data = gets.chomp.to_i
sign = "C" and "F"
Myclass = Class.new do
  puts sign
end
if sign == "C"
  puts data + 1.8 + 32
elsif sign == "F"
  puts (data - 32) * 0.55
end
```

If I do not append the data with `to_i`, I get an error:

```
8:in +': no implicit conversion of fixnum into string
```

Comment: How is the "second" elsif statement not working? I only see one.

Comment: sorry, I have meant just an elsif statement. If to rephrase, how can I append to it if my input will be 50F for example, because right now it does not matter if I will write 50C or 50F it will still execute "if" statement.

Comment: `gets` returns a string as screen input, and it seems that here you're assuming numerical input. Your class is currently redundant, and it's not clear what you mean by `elsif` not working. Currently your sign expression will evaluate to `"C"` every time, if that's what you mean.

Comment: So how may I evaluate it to "F" if I want to?
Basically what I need is: if the user input will be 50C it will do the if statement, but if the input will be 50F it will do the elsif statement.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ Your “C ⇒ F” formula contains an error. One should multiply by `1.8` there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their time! mudasobwa provided an easy and understandable solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = gets.chomp.downcase
deg, meas = data.split(/(?=[cf])/)
case meas
when 'c' then puts 1.8 * deg.to_f + 32
when 'f' then puts (deg.to_f - 32) / 1.8
else puts 'Wrong input. Please enter smth like “50C”'
end
```

Comment: `0.55 *` is a quite coarse approximation. You should use `(deg.to_f - 32) / 1.8` instead.

Comment: @Stefan I have no idea about the intent, maybe it is expected to be corrupted? I have just copy-pasted calculations.

Comment: _"I am converting from C to F and vice-versa"_. Besides, what are the chances that a newbie wants deliberately wrong code? And you've already fixed the "+" :-)

Comment: Thank you guys for the time and help, yes my formula here is a bit out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think a verbose semi-code form of what you're asking is below. Your problem is you have an input of either C or F, and a desired output of either C or F. Thus you need to parameterize this choice and roll it into a function. The `num` is the variable you've called `data`. You could of course do this more tersely, or indeed without an `elsif` but I'm not making an assumption about how you get that value - if it comes in as user input then it's possible that a simple `else` check would lead to a default condition being erroneously hit.

Hopefully that makes sense.

```
def convert(num, input_sign, desired_output_sign)
  output_string = ""

  if (input_sign == "C" && desired_output_sign == "F")
    # do conversion to value
    value = <your conversion code>
    output_string << "#{value}F"
  elsif (input_sign == "F" && desired_output_sign == "C")
    # do conversion to value
    value = <your conversion code>
    output_string << "#{value}C"
  end

  output_string
end
```